# Docker: Capture consolidated cpu and mem usage

Tags: docker, docker-engine, docker-ucp

While I understand we have Docker remote API (https://my.company.docker.net/containers/{containerId}/stats) to get cpu, mem stats among other details for a given container, I would like to get consolidated cpu, mem usage for all docker instances running behind our load balancer.

Let's say load balancer is https://helloworld.lb.net and there are 3 docker container instances that are behind this load balancer to which traffic can go to (namely helloworld.node1.net, helloworld.node2.net and helloworld.node3.net).  I would like to get consolidated cpu, mem usage of these 3 instances and not in individual form as no. of instances to be spun up would be dynamic.

Also note that the load balancer is dynamic and not static.  There might be different load balancers for different business apps likes crmapp.lb.net, anotherapp.lb.net supporting corresponding docker container instances behind.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to orchestrate your Prometheus & Grafanna stack as well and have it dynamically monitor the newly spawned instances . This can be your [Starting Point](https://github.com/vegasbrianc/prometheus)